# Swith remote branches in git

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

Say I have two remote git branches, `A` and `B`.

I want branch `A` to contain the contents of branch `B` and later remove `B`, so that only branch `A` remains with `B`'s original contents.

Unfortunately, the remote repository won't allow my to simply delete the branch `A`, so I'm stuck with somehow copying over `B` into `A`.

Is this possible using only `git` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this is git's core feature. have a look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

```
$ git checkout A
$ git merge B
```

you then could delete B following this answer: [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)